# Ruby 1.9 - Invalid multibyte character (utf-8)

Tags: ruby, vim, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a ruby file with only these two lines:

```
# encoding: utf-8
puts "—"
```

When I run it with `ruby test_enc.rb` it fails with:

```
test_enc.rb:2: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
test_enc.rb:2: unterminated string meets end of file
```

I don't know how to properly specify the character code of `—` (emdash), but vim tells me it is `151, Hex 97, Octal 227`. It fails the same way with other characters like `ã` as well, so I doubt it is related specifically to that character.
I am running on Windows XP and the version of ruby I'm using is:

```
ruby 1.9.1p430 (2010-08-16 revision 28998) [i386-mingw32]
```

I feel like there is something very obvious I am missing here. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Learned a valuable lesson about assumptions today - specifically assuming your editor IS using UTF-8 without actually checking it. Oops!

Thanks for the quick and accurate replies all!

**EDIT AGAIN:** The 'setting up vim properly for utf-8' grew too big and wasn't really relevant to this question, so it is now a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477565/how-to-setup-vim-properly-for-editing-in-utf-8).

Comment: Are you sure it's not coding: utf-8? (rather than encoding).

Comment: Both do the same thing. You can actually put `asdfgibberishcoding: utf-8` and it works just the same.

Comment: What does 'puts _ENCODING_' say? (add one 2 _ each part of _ENCODING_).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that Ruby is explicitly calling your attention to UTF-8, I strongly suspect that you haven't actually written out a UTF-8 file to start with. Make sure that Vim (or whatever text editor you're using to create the file) is *really* set to write out UTF-8.

Note that in UTF-8, any non-ASCII character will be represented by multiple bytes, not a single byte as you've described from the Vim diagnostics. I'd recommend using a binary file editor (or dump, or whatever) to *really* show what's in the text file though. Something that doesn't already have some preconceived notion of the encoding - something that isn't even trying to think of it as a text file.

Notepad lets you write out a file in UTF-8, so you might want to try that just to see what happens. (I don't have Ruby installed myself, otherwise I'd try it for you.)

Comment: I just had the same thought - what is vim *actually* saving the file as?
When I checked I saw its encoding was set to `latin1`. I was wondering why those numbers didn't match up to what I saw in [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=1024&unicodeinhtml=dec).

Comment: Setting the encoding to `ISO-8859-1` (to match what my editor is actually using) appears to fix it. I still see `ù` when I print it out, but I'm pretty sure that's just a windows terminal issue.

Comment: @Nick: Rather than change the encoding in the file, why not change what your editor uses? Then you won't be limited to just Latin-1, which is a pretty small range of characters. I'm *sure* Vim must support other encodings...

Comment: I think you're right, and that will help me long term as well. I'm remembering now a previous time I had problems with encoding and I'm pretty sure the cause was this same darn thing. For any other vim users that see this, put `set encoding=utf-8` in your .vimrc and you'll be set.

Comment: Also, thanks very much for your help, and *wow* you answer questions quickly.

Comment: For any other vim users reading my previous comment, I was wrong, it is not always that easy. It depends on whether you're using vim in a terminal, as well as a few other things, it looks like. When I find the 'best way' to do it I'll link to it at the end of my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your file is in latin1. Ruby is right.

emdash would be encoded on two bytes not one in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, your comment is spot on. :)

Comment: Three, actually: `0xE2 0x80 0x94`.

Comment: @Jörg : that's what I guess for not checking ;)