# How to setup vim properly for editing in utf-8

Tags: vim, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I've run into problems a few times because vim's encoding was set to latin1 by default and I didn't notice and assumed it was using utf-8. Now that I have, I'd like to set up vim so that it will do the right thing in all obvious cases, and use utf-8 by default.

**What I'd like to avoid:**

- Forcing a file saved in some other encoding *that would have worked before my changes* to open as utf-8, resulting in gibberish.
- Forcing a terminal that doesn't support multibyte characters (like the Windows XP one) to try to display them anyway, resulting in gibberish.
- Interfering with other programs' ability to read or edit the files (I have a (perhaps unjustified) aversion to using a BOM by default because I am unclear on how likely it is to mess other programs up.)
- Other issues that I don't know enough about to guess at (but hopefully you do!)

**What I've got so far:**

```
if has("multi_byte")
  if &termencoding == ""
    let &termencoding = &encoding
  endif
  set encoding=utf-8                     " better default than latin1
  setglobal fileencoding=utf-8           " change default file encoding when writing new files
  "setglobal bomb                        " use a BOM when writing new files
  set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1 " order to check for encodings when reading files
endif
```

This is taken and slightly modified from the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode). I moved the `bomb` from `setglobal fileencoding` to its own statement because otherwise it doesn't actually work. I also commented out that line because of my uncertainty towards BOMs.

**What I'm looking for:**

- Possible pitfalls to avoid that I missed
- Problems with the existing code
- Links to anywhere this has been discussed / set out already

Ultimately, I'd like this to result in a no-thought-required copy/paste snippet that will set up vim for utf-8-by-default that will work across platforms.

**EDIT:** I've marked my own answer as accepted for now, as far as I can tell it works okay and accounts for all things it can reasonably account for. But it's not set in stone; if you have any new information please feel free to answer!

Comment: Hey Nick, did you get that from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode)? It has some decent explanation of the bits.

Comment: Yes I did, as I had hoped I made clear. The first sentence directly under the code block links to it and says "This is taken and slightly modified from the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode)".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In response to sehe, I'll give a go at answering my own question! I removed the updates I made to the original question and have moved them to this answer. This is probably the better way to do it.

**The answer:**

```
if has("multi_byte")
  if &termencoding == ""
    let &termencoding = &encoding
  endif
  set encoding=utf-8                     " better default than latin1
  setglobal fileencoding=utf-8           " change default file encoding when writing new files
endif
```

I removed the `bomb` line because according to the [BOM Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) it is not needed when using utf-8 and in fact defeats ASCII backwards compatibility. As long as `ucs-bom` is first in `fileencodings`, vim will be able to detect and handle existing files with BOMs, so it is not needed for that either.

I removed the `fileencodings` line because it is not needed in this case. From the [Vim docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27fileencodings%27): `When 'encoding' is set to a Unicode encoding, and 'fileencodings' was not set yet, the default for 'fileencodings' is changed.`

I am using `setglobal filencoding` (as opposed to `set fileencoding`) because:
When reading a file, `fileencoding` will be automatically set based on `fileencodings`. So it only matters for new files then. And according to the [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27fenc%27) again:

> For a new file the global value of
>   'fileencoding' is used.

Comment: This snippet is going straight into my rc file. A very important step in my crusade against Latin-1. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help.

Comment: Great. I refound this information as I'm now self a victim of WinXP... :) SO is also a public notebook like that!

Comment: Which terminal did you use for this to work? And is this gVim or console Vim?

Comment: I usually use MacVim or gVim, but these settings **should** work across all console and graphical interfaces. When I wrote this I probably tried it on whatever Ubuntu's default terminal is, the Win7 terminal, and iTerm 2.

Comment: "...the default for `fileencodings` is changed" - hmm. Not sure I really understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would suffice to have a vanilla vimrc + fenc=utf-8

The rest should be pretty decent out-of-the-box

I'd use the BOM only on Windows platforms with Microsoft tooling (although even some of these fail to always write a BOM; however it is the default for Notepad Unicode saving, .NET XmlWriter and other central points of the MS platform tools)

Comment: That's good to know about the BOM on Windows platforms, thanks! Unfortunately, opening a utf-8 file with only `fenc=utf-8` in my .vimrc doesn't quite cut it. Opening my test file with that gives me the following: `ï»¿should have a BOM and be in utf-8 'â€’'`

Comment: On what platform is that? On my linux box, `fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1` by default, so it would have worked. This is on Ubuntu Maverick, vim 7.2 (patches 1-330) and no encoding related flags in (global) vimrc or debian.vim

Comment: On Windows XP, vim 7.3. That's actually pretty interesting. I assumed there would be some differences from platform to platform, but it's nice to have a concrete example of this problem.

Comment: What is the default value of fencs on WinXP/7.3?

Comment: Looks like it is `fileencodings=ucs-bom`.

Comment: Although, when I `set encoding=utf-8`, it changes to `fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1`. So maybe setting fileencodings explicitly is unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, here's a quote from the documentation: `When 'encoding' is set to a Unicode encoding, and 'fileencodings' was
 not set yet, the default for 'fileencodings' is changed.`

Comment: Well, your answer as-is doesn't, no. If you update it to include the information from these comments, then I will though!

Comment: Gah sorry, and one more thing: maybe mention why you're setting `fenc=utf-8` instead of `setglobal fenc=utf-8` (which is what I had in the question)

Comment: Aha, you mean using setglobal works? Good to know. In that case, I'd rather see you add that as a separate answer yourself, so we can upvote it!

Comment: Okay, I moved the updates I was making to the original question to a separate answer - this is probably the better way to represent this anyway. Thanks!