# Is there a command you can enter into a Vim _gvimrc file to set default encoding and line endings?

Tags: vim, encoding, utf-8, line-endings

Is there a command you can enter into a `_gvimrc` file to set default encoding and line endings?

I'm working on a Windows machine but i would like to create and edit files using UTF-8 encoding (no BOM) and standard Unix line endings (\n).

Can i set Vim up to create files with these specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of reading and experimenting:

Set these in `_gvimrc`

```
set encoding=utf-8                      "Set default buffer encoding to UTF-8.
set fileencodings=utf-8,latin1          "Set the order of file encodings when reading and creating files.
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac            "Set the order of line endings when reading and creating files.
```

These should be used in the command line.

```
set fileencoding=utf-8                  "Change an opened file's encoding.
set fileformat=unix                     "Change an opened file's line endings.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, put this to your gvimrc:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileformat=unix
```

You can use the `:h[elp]` command to get additional info, e.g. `:h encoding`

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE***:
*I realize that you specifically asked for a setting for your `vimrc` file but I thought I would offer this bit of advice anyway because I suspect that you may benefit from it (you may be using both *nix and Windows like me).*

I do work on both *nix and Windows and I have found it a lot easier to use the `modeline` feature (see: `:help modeline`) in lieu of setting the file format in my RC file. This allows me to have something like: `vim:ff=unix` at the bottom of each file (This way, I do not have to worry about changing the line endings for a *nix makefile I happen to edit in/on Windows.

HTH

Comment: It should be noted that vim has had several remote vulnerabilities
discovered within modeline support.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477565/how-to-setup-vim-properly-for-editing-in-utf-8), that should cover all of your vim encoding bases.

Quote from linked answer, with your line ending preferences added in:

```
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac 
if has("multi_byte")
  if &termencoding == ""
    let &termencoding = &encoding
  endif
  set encoding=utf-8                     " better default than latin1
  setglobal fileencoding=utf-8           " change default file encoding when writing new files
endif
```