# Problems pasting unicode into vim under windows

Tags: powershell, vim, unicode, windows-8.1

So I've just started using Vim and got a wierd problem with unicode.

I'm running on windows and using the editor in powershell.
Powershell doesnt seem to be the problem as I can paste the relevant text into a command prompt without it being distorted.

I was initially having problems with unicode everywhere but after adding the following to my vimrc

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

Things work for everything except for pasting unicode text in.  I'm currently working around this by pasting text into the file in notepad++ saving in there and then reloading in vim.  The paste method I'm using in vim is to go into insert mode and right click.  EDIT I've just tried using the alternate shift+Insert way of pasting from the clipboard but that doesnt appear to work at all

I've also tried following using [the vimrc config suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477565/how-to-setup-vim-properly-for-editing-in-utf-8) but it hasn't helped.

EDIT just realised I get problems pasting quotes (either single or double) into vim aswell... although its possible they are some crazy character as they are coming out of outlook.

Any pointers on this would be really useful.

Comment: In your vimrc, do you have, `behave mswin` (also look at help entries for both behave and mswin)?

Comment: @Patrick no I don't just had a look at the documentation as you suggested and that seems to be all about the mouse.  Do you think it will help here?

Comment: Okay, the command calling `mswin.vim` plugin (`source $VIMRUNTIME\mswin.vim`) and not `behave mswin` would perform the mapping between the clipboard register and `<C-V>` (and other MS clipboard functionality).  Your solution resolves the issue from Vim's approach.

Comment: @Patrick yeah I'm resisting the temptation to start mapping my own shortcuts just yet - still learning the basics really

Answer (score 3):

I have found a workaround:

using `"*p` to paste works fine for some reason... as does (in insert mode) `C-r *`.

Both of those are just saying paste in what is in register `*` which is the system clipboard register.

I discovered this by trying to use cmd rather than powershell as there's no option to right-click to paste in cmd.

I have checked and this method of pasting works in powershell aswell.

Moral of the story - use the built-in vim stuff rather than whatever is going on when you right click paste in powershell